# Integer programming formulation for the entire region of a triangle except the region of a rectangle inside it

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Suppose we have a triangle-shaped region such as:

> $x-y\ge0$
>
> $x+y\le8$
>
> $x,y\ge0$ and integers

How to write an IP formulation to describe all real points inside this triangle except the points inside the rectangle (Only the red-shaded region) as depicted in the figure below:
[image: Red shaded region]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enforce
$$\lnot(3 < x < 5 \land 1 < y < 2),$$
equivalently,
$$x \le 3 \lor x \ge 5 \lor y \le 1 \lor y \le 2.$$
Introduce binary variables $z_i$ for $i \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ and linear constraints:
\begin{align}
x - 3 &\le (8-3)(1-z_1) \tag1\\
5 - x &\le (5-0)(1-z_2) \tag2\\
y - 1 &\le (4-1)(1-z_3) \tag3\\
2 - y &\le (2-0)(1-z_4) \tag4\\
\sum_{i=1}^4 z_i &\ge 1 \tag5
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ enforces $z_1=1 \implies x \le 3$.
Constraint $(2)$ enforces $z_2=1 \implies x \ge 5$.
Constraint $(3)$ enforces $z_3=1 \implies y \le 1$.
Constraint $(4)$ enforces $z_4=1 \implies y \ge 2$.
Constraint $(5)$ enforces $\lor_i (z_i = 1)$.